# Is it possible to add your app to iOS 11 control center or make accessible from lock screen?

Tags: ios, swift, lockscreen

I am writing an app for iPhone that I would like to be able to access from the lock screen. One way I could think of doing this is adding it to control center and since the control center revamp in iOS 11 which added more customization it seems more likely now that you would be able to add your app to it. Anyways if you know how to do this or know another method of allowing access to your app from the lock screen or its just simply not possible I would a appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don´t think you can add your own app in the control center, not yet at least. The easiest way to access your app from a lock screen would be to add a [today extension (widget)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html).

You can add a target on your widget, which will open your app if a user clicks on it. You can do that like this in your widget:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "AppName://home")
self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
```